# Ist „wie zum Beispiel“ eine Wiederholung?

Tags: sentence-structure

Einfach so. Ist der Ausdruck *„wie zum Beispiel“* eine Wiederholung?

*Ursprung der Frage*: Dass man (vielleicht) das *wie* bzw. das *zum Beispiel* ausfallen lassen darf:

> - Er kennt sich überhaupt nicht mit Begriffen, *wie zum Beispiel X, Y…*  , aus.
> - Er kennt sich überhaupt nicht mit Begriffen, *wie X, Y,…*  , aus.
> - Er kennt sich überhaupt nicht mit Begriffen, *zum Beispiel* (mit) *X, Y…*  , aus.

Comment: Das dritte Beispiel hat IMHO eine andere Bedeutung, aber der Unterschied ist sehr diffizil. Deutlicher wird das z.B. wenn man sagt "Er kennt sich überhaupt nicht mit Verben, wie gehen, laufen,… aus." - Hier soll der Leser einen Zusammenhang herstellen (sinng. also "Er kennt sich überhaupt nicht mit Verben der Bewegung aus."). Auf der anderen Seite bedeutet "Er kennt sich überhaupt nicht mit Verben, zum Beispiel gehen, laufen… , aus." schlicht "Er kennt sich überhaupt nicht mit Verben aus." - Hier wird nur dem Leser verdeutlicht, was ein Verb überhaupt ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wort *wie* ist hier eine Konjunktion (genau: eine Vergleichspartikel). Es verbindet also den Begriff mit dem Vergleich. Es transportiert natürlich ein Stück weit die Idee von "Beispiel" aber es hat darüber hinaus auch syntaktische Funktion.

*Zum Beispiel* ist eine adverbiale Bestimmung und hat keine solche syntaktische Komponente. 
Daher kann *zum Beispiel* weggelassen werden, *wie* aber nicht. 
In deinem Beispiel ändert sich der Sinn meiner Ansicht nach kaum, egal ob mit oder ohne *zum Beispiel*. Aber das ist nicht immer der Fall.

> Ich bin in Französisch nicht so gut wie in Englisch und Deutsch.

Wenn ich hier *zum Beispiel* sage, impliziere ich, dass ich noch andere Sprachen leidlich gut spreche.

Comment: @c.p. da bin ich mir nicht sicher (könnte ein Apposition sein), aber ich glaube, ich würde keins setzen :)

Comment: @c.p. Ohne Komma möglich, es sei denn du möchtest es hervorheben (suggeriert auch eine Sprechpause).

Answer (score 2):

Wie bereits in der Antwort von Emanuel erwähnt, ist [*wie* eine Vergleichspartikel](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wie#Vergleichspartikel). Im ersteren Sinne ziehst du also einen Vergleich zwischen zwei Objekten.

> Du bist so schlau wie ein Fuchs.

Hier wäre das Hinzufügen von "zum Beispiel" falsch, weil du kein Beispiel aufzählst, sondern nur einen Vergleich anstellst.

Fügst du Beispiele an, so ist *wie* (immer noch eine Vergleichspartikel) aussagekräftig genug und benötigt grundsätzlich kein zusätzliches *zum Beispiel*:

> Großprojekte(,) wie Stuttgart 21 und der Berliner Flughafen(,) kosten viel Geld.

In der Praxis wird häufig *zum Beispiel* oder *beispielsweise* angehängt:

> Großprojekte(,) wie beispielsweise Stuttgart 21 und der Berliner Flughafen(,) kosten viel Geld.

Das ist absolut OK und wird auch von jenen benutzt, die von sich behaupten, die deutsche Sprache zu beherrschen. Das zeigt beispielsweise eine [Google-Suche für die Site sprachlog.de](https://www.google.de/search?client=opera&q=site:sprachlog.de%20%22wie%20zum%20Beispiel%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest).

Praktisch gesehen handelt es sich um eine redundante Information, welche aber nicht nur gängig ist, sondern sogar kaum bemängelt wird. Dennoch ist es ratsam, wenn man in Facharbeiten die Dopplung meidet oder zumindest nicht übermäßig verwendet. Es gibt nämlich dennoch einige, die es für schlechten Stil halten (bei Korrekturlesungen meiner Bachelorarbeit wurde mir damals das ein oder andere *zum Beispiel* rausgestrichen).

Wie in der anderen Antwort gesagt, kann *wie* nicht ausgelassen werden, wenn Beispiele im Textfluss angeführt werden. Es ist sozusagen die notwendige Bedingung. *Zum Beispiel* indes ist nur die hinreichende Bedingung. Selbstverständlich bleibt aber noch die Möglichkeit, Beispiele loszukoppeln und nachträglich anzufügen. Oder ein konkretes Beispiel wird genauer untersucht. In beiden Fällen steht *zum Beispiel* (oder *beispielsweise*) alleine.

> Großprojekte kosten viel Geld. Ich denke da zum Beispiel an Stuttgart 21 und den Berliner Flughafen.
>   Großprojekte kosten viel Geld. Beispielsweise kostet Stuttgart 21 mehrere Millionen Euro.

An der Stelle ist ein *wie* konsequenterweise falsch, weil hier die Beispielsangabe keinem Vergleich mehr entspricht.

Comment: mehrere Millionen Euro. Das ist dann wohl ein Euphemismus :)

Comment: @Emanuel Nun, trivial erfüllt, da eine Milliarde 1000 Millionen sind und 1000 unbedingt unter "mehrere" fällt :)

Answer (score 1):

In Duden – *Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* sowie Duden – *Das Stilwörterbuch* findet man unter dem Lemma *wie* mit der Bedeutung „schließt zur Veranschaulichung ein oder mehrere Beispiele an“ sowohl ein Beispiel, bei dem *wie* allein steht

> Haustiere wie Rinder, Schweine, Pferde

als auch

> Entwicklungsländer wie zum Beispiel Somalia und Tansania
>   Entwicklungsländer wie beispielsweise Somalia und Tansania
>   Entwicklungsländer wie etwa Somalia und Tansania
>   Entwicklungsländer wie meinetwegen Somalia und Tansania

Darüber hinaus steht der Ausdruck „wie zum Beispiel“ auch im Duden – *Redewendungen* und im Duden – *Das Synonymwörterbuch*. Er ist also durchaus üblich und wird nicht als umgangssprachlich oder gar schlechter Stil bewertet, auch wenn in vielen Fällen *wie* allein genügt, ohne missverständlich zu sein.

Was man aber laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* tatsächlich vermeiden sollte, ist, am Anfang und am Ende einer Aufzählung anzuzeigen, dass nur eine Auswahl von Beispielen gegeben wird. Es genügt, wenn man entweder am Anfang durch *zum Beispiel* oder *wie* oder am Ende der Aufzählung durch *u. a., usf., usw.* oder *etc.* darauf hinweist.

> Sie hat viele Länder besucht, z. B. Österreich, Holland.
>   Sie hat viele Länder besucht: Österreich, Holland u. a.
>   <s>Sie hat viele Länder besucht, z. B. Österreich, Holland u. a.</s>